# Relationship between injectivity of induced map of fundamental groups and restriction of covering space to open submanifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a connected manifold, $U\subset X$ be an open submanifold of $X$ such that $\pi_1 U\to \pi_1 X$ is injective.

**How can I prove the universal covering $\widetilde{U}\to U$ is the restriction of the universal covering  $\widetilde{X}\to X$?**

I guess it will need some knowledge about the Deck transformation group and covering space. But I have no idea how to give a proof. Could you please give me some help with the details? Thank you very much!

Comment: I am assuming $p\colon\widetilde X\to X$ is the universal covering of $X$ and $\widetilde U=p^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: **Covering Checking:** Let $V\subseteq_\text{open} X$ with $p^{-1}(V)=\bigsqcup \widetilde{V_i}$, $\widetilde{V_i}\subseteq_\text{open} \widetilde X$,  $p\big|\widetilde{V_i}\xrightarrow{\cong} V$. Then we have  $p^{-1}(V\cap U)=\bigsqcup(\widetilde{V_i}\cap\widetilde U)$,  $\widetilde{V_i}\cap \widetilde U\subseteq_\text{open}\widetilde U$, $p\big|\widetilde{V_i}\cap \widetilde U\xrightarrow{\cong} V\cap U$.

Comment: **Checking simply-connectedness of each component of $\widetilde U$:** Let $\gamma$ be a loop in some component $\widetilde {U_0}$ of $\widetilde U$. Note that the restriction map $p_0=p\big|\widetilde {U_0}\to U$ is a covering. Hence, induced map $p_{0*}$ on the fundamental groups is injective. Let $i\colon U \hookrightarrow X$ and $j_0\colon \widetilde{U_0}\hookrightarrow \widetilde X$ be the inclusions.

Comment: Now,  the composite map $\Phi:=\pi_1\left(\widetilde {U_0}\right)\xrightarrow{p_{0*}}\pi_1(U)\xrightarrow{i_*}\pi_1(X)$, is same as the composite map $\Psi:=\pi_1\left(\widetilde{ U_0}\right)\xrightarrow{j_{0*}}\pi_1\left(\widetilde X\right)\xrightarrow{p_*}\pi_1(X)$ as $i\circ p_0=p\circ j_0$ . 

Note that $\Psi=0$ as $\pi_1\left(\widetilde X\right)=0$. Also, $\Phi$ is injective as it is the composition of two injective maps. Therefore, $\Phi\big([\gamma]\big)=\Psi\big([\gamma]\big)=0$. This implies $[\gamma]$ is the trivial element of $\pi_1\left(\widetilde{U_0}\right)$.

Comment: what if $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$ is not the universal covering of $X$, it is just any covering? @SumantaDas

Comment: Then consider only covering checking part.

Comment: Do you mean that the assumption on the injectivity of the induced map between fundamental groups is Not Essential in that case that the covering is not universal?  Because the injectivity is only used in the second part: checking simply-connectedness of each component $\widetilde{U}$. I'm a little confused.  @SumantaDas

Comment: I vote to close your question because you do not explain what $\tilde U$ and $\tilde X$ are.

Comment: Of course I can see that $\tilde U \to U$ and $\tilde X \to X$ are coverings. But which coverings? If you mean universal coverings, you should say this and edit your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ok, I got it. I will edit it.

Comment: I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. Take $X = S^1$ and $U = S^1_+$ = open upper half circle. The universal covering of $X$ is $p : \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) =e^{i t}$, and the universal covering of $U$ is the identity $id_U$. The restriction of $p$ to $U$ is given as $p : p^{-1}(U) \to U$. But $p^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} (2n \pi, (2n+1)\pi)$.

Comment: Actually, the $U=S_+^1$ can  be expressed by $p(t)=e^{it}$ with $2n\pi<t<(2n+1)\pi$. So I think they may coincide in this sense. And then the answer given by Sumanta Das is right.

Comment: @988786 It is well-known that the restriction $p : p^{-1}(U) \to U$ of an arbitrary covering $p : \tilde X \to X$ to $U \subset X$ is always a covering. But to be the *universal covering* the space $p^{-1}(U)$ must be simply connected which is not true in my example ($p^{-1}(U)$ is not even path connected). And, by the way, you do not require $U$ to be connected which would be a minimal assumption to get a universal covering by restriction.